# nginx HTTPS redirect is not triggered when IP address is used

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for my public EC2 instance. I have:

- A nice, clean public domain
- An AWS-generated public domain (*.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
- An AWS-generated public IP address

I would like to have all traffic go over HTTPS to the public domain. I attempted to do this by creating a "primary" server block configured to route to my application, with two secondary server blocks to catch all other traffic and redirect to https://public.domain.com. This is what my config looks like:

```
# "Primary" block
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  public.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    # Other config; SSL config
}

# Catch-all redirects
server {
    listen      80;

    return 301 https://public.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen      443;

    return 301 https://public.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

In testing this, I get the following results:

- http://public.domain.com  >> https://public.domain.com (correct)
- http://2308.compute-1.amazonaws.com >> https://public.domain.com (correct)
- http**s**://2308.compute-1.amazonaws.com >> No redirect (**WRONG!**)
- http://55.255.255.255 >> https://public.domain.com (correct)
- http**s**://55.255.255.255 >> No redirect (**WRONG!**)

Why is nginx not redirecting my HTTPS traffic to my public domain? Is the `server_name` not used in the URL matching process?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have default server set on port 443, so nginx takes the first defined host, which is `server_name  public.domain.com;`

Use `listen 443 ssl default_server`, also you need a wildcard certificate for your redirect server for this config to work (self-signed, clients will show a warning anyway, if host does not match)

See https://serverfault.com/questions/578648/properly-setting-up-a-default-nginx-server-for-https